# Double Possessive?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Is it correct to say:

“The employee of Donald Trump’s”

Or should one say:

“The employee of Donald Trump”?

ie is the “‘s” redundant or not?

Comment: "Donald Trump's employee" sounds more natural to me